# Javers recreating table during Application startup

Tags: javers

We updated our apps to latest Spring version and updated Javers version, after doing so apps failed during start up with following logs

```
   2019-10-17 19:51:37,309 30688 ERROR [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication [SpringApplication.java:821] --- Application run failed 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'JPADeleteAspect': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'javers'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'javers' defined in class path resource [com/common/audit/JaversSpringJpaApplicationConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.polyjdbc.core.exception.SchemaManagerException: [DDL_ERROR] Failed to run DDL:
    CREATE TABLE jv_commit (
    commit_pk NUMBER NOT NULL,
    author VARCHAR2(200),
    commit_date TIMESTAMP,
    commit_date_instant VARCHAR2(30),
    commit_id NUMBER(22,2),
    CONSTRAINT jv_commit_pk PRIMARY KEY(commit_pk)
    ) 
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202)
        at 
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'javers' defined in class path resource [com/common/audit/JaversSpringJpaApplicationConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.polyjdbc.core.exception.SchemaManagerException: [DDL_ERROR] Failed to run DDL:
    CREATE TABLE jv_commit (
    commit_pk NUMBER NOT NULL,
    author VARCHAR2(200),
    commit_date TIMESTAMP,
    commit_date_instant VARCHAR2(30),
    commit_id NUMBER(22,2),
    CONSTRAINT jv_commit_pk PRIMARY KEY(commit_pk)
    )

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:193)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:999)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1315)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1890)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1855)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:304)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
    at org.polyjdbc.core.schema.SchemaManagerImpl.ddl(SchemaManagerImpl.java:88)
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

We initially thought issue was because of multiple apps using old and new versions of Javers pointing to same DB. We created new DB just for apps using latest Javers and the application started without any issues the very first time , and further restarts failed with the same error as above.

Javers dependency used

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javers/javers-spring-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
        <artifactId>javers-spring-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javers/javers-spring-boot-starter-sql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
        <artifactId>javers-spring-boot-starter-sql</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

We are using spring version : 5.1.8, Oracle dialect 12c.
```

Comment: Does the error happens also in the latest version (5.8.3)?

Comment: Yes , I tried with 5.8.3 as well

Comment: If you are able to reproduce this issue in a failing test case, please report it here https://github.com/javers/javers/issues. You can add your test case to OracleDockerIntegrationTest.groovy or OracleDockerIntegrationWithSchemaTest.groovy

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens to me before, the issue is the wrong Javers version implemented into your project.

If you are using Java version 8 or older, it is best to use Javers 6.14.0 (the latest version of Javers today).
If you are using Java version 9 or newer, it is best to use Javers 7.0.0 or newer.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).